# Error: cannot find Integer symbol when doing parseInt

Tags: java, symbol-not-found

I have been looking for the answer to this problem for a good while now since it seems most of the times its something simple. I am trying to read line by line of a file and on some instances convert the string into a number. When i write my code the `Interger.parseInt` simply doesnt work. I have tried everything from changing the scope of the varaible to leaving it as a string then converting after finishing the loop but it simply says `Interger` in `Interger.parseInt` cannot be found.

```
package inputout;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class readfilebuffer {

    private String Resname;
    private int numberTables;
    private int[] maxpertable;
    private int[] sbm;
    private String[] line4;

    public void readFile1(File fin) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fin);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(count==0 )
                Resname = line;
                if(count==1)
                    numberTables = Interger.parseInt(line);//Interger here "cannot be found"
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println(numberTables);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and at `count==1` i have this line being read in `4` and when i print the value in `numberTablles` is 0.

Comment: Say `Interger` a few more times out loud. If English isn't your first language, look up that term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 3):

Your "`Interger`" has **a typo**:  it is "`Integer`"  (you have an extra "r" in there).

Comment: @Jovis13 You really should accept this answer. No better one will be forthcoming, because there isn't a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You've just misspelled it. You've typed `Interger` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Why not just use an IDE like Eclipse? It will make you write your code easier than a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
public class readfilebuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Resname;
        int numberTables = 0;
        int[] maxpertable;
        int[] sbm;
        String[] line4;
        int temp=0,temp1=0;

        int count = 0;
        try {
            File fin = new File(fin);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fin);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                   numberTables = Integer.parseInt(line);//Interger here "cannot be found"
                   //System.out.println(numberTables);

                   count++;

                   if(count == 1) {
                       temp = numberTables;
                   }

                   if(count == 2) {
                       temp1 = numberTables;               
                   }
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println(temp1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this answer has been flagged as a low quality answer, please provide some explanation :)